# Migrating a wordpress blog from one server to another server preserving the folder /blog

Tags: dns, blogs, directory, migrate

I'm migrating a blog from server1 to a new server2.
In the server1 I have a rails web in ​​http://mydomain.com and wordpress blog in http://mydomain.com/blog
This is so for SEO reasons.

Now I need to migrate the blog to server2 but I need to keep the same URL mydomain.com/blog on the new server2.

The rails web needs to stay on the server1 mydomain.com and the domain DNS is pointing to server1.
The problem is how to make mydomain.com/blog point to server2.

Someone can tell me how to do that? I am aware that a subdomain blog.mydomain.com could do it but like I said, for SEO reasons It must remain on a folder /blog.

Any Idea? I'm really lost right now

Comment: will 301 redirect work for you ?

Comment: 301 redirect is not what I'm searching for :(

Comment: you can add aname record to map /blog to point to ip address of server 2 then.

Comment: aname records only works with subdomains not for folders. I need mydomain.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily achieve what you are trying to do. It is not possible to map a folder to a diffrent server without redirecting or proxying.

For proxying have a look at [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).